# No autocompletion of JavaScript code in PhpStorm html files

Tags: phpstorm

I recently upgraded my PhpStorm IDE to Version 2017.2 Build #PS-172.3317.83, JS code auto completion in html files was disabled.

Is it an issue with IDE or am I missing some settings?

Comment: What files again? It works in `*.html` files fine but not in `*.php`. To fix that -- update PhpStorm to the latest 2017.2.1 version.

Comment: Thanks, the latest update sorted me